# C++ std::cout displaying 64

Tags: c++, hex, decimal

`std::cout << 100 << std::endl;`

I've written this code but when I go to see the result it prints 64? Anyone has any ideia why this is?

Comment: Please show all of the code. `cout` was probably imbued with a modifier that changes the base of displayed numbers. Also is this C++ or C++/CLI? Those are different languages and you should only tag with one of them.

Comment: 64 is hexadecimal 100, that's a hint.

Comment: Did someone (possibly you) set your stream to [`hex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) mode?

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Yes a did a few lines before, how do I turn it back?

Comment: `std::cout << std::dec` will do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << 100 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << 100 << std::endl;
    std::cout << 100 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::dec << 100 << std::endl;
    std::cout << 100 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
100
64
64
100
100
```

You got the output `64` because somewhere in the preceding code there was used the standard manipulator `std::hex`.

Comment: OOoooo Ooo oooooooo! Can we have it in octal, too?